# Efficient calculation of cosine in python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, trigonometry

I generate some time-series out of a theoretical power spectral density.

Basically, my function in time-space is given by `X(t) = SUM_n sqrt(a_n) + cos(w_n t + phi_n)`, where `a_n` is the value of the `PSD` at a given `w_n` and `phi` is some random phase. To get a realistic timeseries, i have to sum up `2^25` modes, and my `t` of course is sized `2^25` as well.

If i do that with python, this will take some weeks...
Is there any way to speed this up? Like some vector calculation?

```
t_full = np.linspace(0,1e-2,2**12, endpoint = False) 
signal = np.zeros_like(t_full)
 for i in range(w.shape[0]):
        signal += dataCOS[i] * np.cos(2*np.pi* t_full * w[i] + random.uniform(0,2*np.pi))
```

where dataCOS is sqrt a_n, w = w and random.uniform represents the random phase shift phi

Comment: Are your `w_n` arbitrary values, or do they look something like `w_n = 2 * np.pi * n / T`?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `outer` functions to calculate the angles and then sum along one axis to obtain your signal in a vectorized way:

```
import numpy as np

t_full = np.linspace(0, 1e-2, 2**12, endpoint=False)
thetas = np.multiply.outer((2*np.pi*t_full), w)
thetas += 2*pi*np.random.random(thetas.shape)

signal = np.cos(thetas)
signal *= dataCOS

signal = signal.sum(-1)
```

This is faster because when you use a Python `for` loop the interpreter will loop at a slower speed compared to a `C` loop. In this case, using numpy outer operations allow you to compute the multiplications and sums at the `C` loop speed.

Comment: okay, maybe my question was not clear enough I use alreads arrys (t is an array) bit i have to sum of some billions of mode, each consiting of of a timesample of cosines!

Comment: @user2003965 It would be nice if you could make your question a little be clearer. Could you give an example of the process you are willing to do?

Comment: Okay, this seems to give me the same result, but can you explain to me why this is faster?

Comment: @user2003965 I've updated the answer adding some info, but in summary, using numpy vectirized functions allow you to access from Python a `C` loop speed...

Comment: One problem: As soon as w or t_full overcomes 2**12, i get the error "array is too big" -> But i have to sum over 2**23 modes... and ideas on that :/

Comment: @user2003965 I'm checking if `numpy` has some parameter to increase this threshold...

Comment: @user2003965 I haven't found anything like a simple parameter that you can change in order to bypass the `array is too big` error. You have some alternatives like dividing the `0 to 0.01` interval in 10 sub-intervals. In this way, you would avoid the memory issue and use only 10 Python loops, which will be not that bad in terms of performance

Comment: ? I did not downvote, i liked the approach and am thankful for your help!

Comment: Is there any efficient way to split this up into several smaller sums that can be computed in parallel with multiprocessing?

Comment: @user2003965 yes, this is pretty much straightforward and worth another question!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19384381/efficient-calculation-of-cosine-in-python-ii

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39283/discussion-between-saullo-castro-and-user2003965)